# Lists into Dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

**file.txt**

```
Harry Moon, Meteor \n roger gim, astronaut \n john banks, westpac \n john banks, ASB
```

**Code:**

```
FILE=file.txt
filename=open(FILE,"rt")
fileread=filename.readlines()
fileread.sort()
for i in fileread:
    dict={}
    dict[i.split(',')[0]]=i.split(',')[1]
    print dict
```

With that, I was able to obtain the following:

```
{'Harry Moon': ' Meteor\n'}
{'john banks': ' ASB'}
{'john banks': ' westpac\n'}
{'roger gim': ' astronaut\n'}
```

However, what I want is this:

```
{ 'Harry Moon': ' Meteor'
   , 'john banks': ' ASB'
   , 'john banks': ' westpac'
   , 'roger gim': 'astronaut' }
```

Comment: You can't get what you want, because your example has two `john banks` keys, and that doesn't work.  Would something like `'john banks': ['ASB', 'westpac']` work instead, i.e. use a list as the value?

Comment: Oh, but it has to work because I was requested to turn a file with many duplicate keys with different values into a dictionary. So, I was hoping to split keys and values by recognising the separator, in this case ',' and planning to turn that sliced list into dict so i can call any key to get their value, and even if theyve got duplicates the n duplicates key doesnt have to show, just the value.

Comment: type `d = {'john banks': 'ASB', 'john banks': 'westpac'}` at the Python console.  Then `print d`.

Comment: I basically created an empty list, and then created a few statement to check if name in file.txt is already in the empty list or not if not list.append(name from file.txt); and I finally end with list of name with duplicate. Now I just need to figure out how to put together the list name and list of workplace into dictionary. anyone familiar with zip() method

Answer (score 1):

```
dict([line.strip().split(',') for line in open(FILE).readlines()])
```

Comment: Beat me to it :D  Nice concise answer.

Comment: Actually, this could be more condensed. The call to readlines was not necessary since file objects are already iterables and yield lines when you iterate over them.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use "dict" as a variable name, also use `with` when opening files:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
   result = dict(line.strip().split(',') for line in f)
```

Comment: I will try this, thank you elyase, I will pop back again if somehow I cant arrange the script given. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
file_str = open(FILE).read()

d = {}
for line in file_str.splitlines():
    d[line.split(',')[0]] = line.split(',')[1]

print d
```

There's also John Smith Optionals answer, for really concise code.